# Can I include a file from zip in PHP?

Tags: php

Can I include a file from a zip file in PHP? For example consider I have a zip file - test.zip and test.zip contains a file by the name a.php. Now, what I would like to do is something like below,

include "test.zip/a.php";

Is this possible? If it is can anyone provide me a code snippet?? If not, id there any other alternative to do this??

Comment: I don't think you can do that directly. But you could [unzip it](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20zip%20unpack) first.

Comment: whether you think you can include file with path like `include "zipped.zip/a.php";` I dont think.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive('test.zip');

$tmp = tmpfile();
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data($tmp);

file_put_content($metadata['uri'], $zip->getFromName('a.php'));

include $metadata['uri'];
```

To go further, you may be interested in [PHAR](http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) archive, which basically a Zip archive.

**Edit:**

With a cache strategy:

```
if (apc_exists('test_zip_a_php')) {
    $content = apc_fetch('test_zip_a_php');
} else {
    $zip = new ZipArchive('test.zip');
    $content = $zip->getFromName('a.php');
    apc_add('test_zip_a_php', $content);
}

$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
fwrite($f, $content);
rewind($f);
// Note to use such include you need  `allow_url_include` directive sets to `On`
include('data://text/plain,'.stream_get_contents($f));
```

Comment: Perfect! However, @OP, you might want to find a more efficient way to doing this, as you're practically unzipping every time the page loads. How about caching the file?

Comment: yup, indeed, that's not the most efficient way, first to avoid I/O writing delay, you may use `php://memory` context stream to write the result of the file in memory instead of the disk.
The content could also be cached using apc

Comment: Edited with a simple cache system

Answer (score 2):

Are you all sure? According to the phar extension, phar is implemented using a **stream wrapper**, so they can just call

```
include 'phar:///path/to/myphar.phar/file.php';
```

But there also exists stream wrappers for zip, see [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php#example-835), where they call:

```
$reader->open('zip://' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.odt#meta.xml');
```

To open the file meta.xml in the zip-File `test.odt` (odt-files are only zip-files with another extension).

Also in [another example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstream.php#example-854) they directly open a zip file via stream wrapper:

```
$im = imagecreatefromgif('zip://' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/test_im.zip#pear_item.gif');
imagepng($im, 'a.png');
```

I have to admit, I do not know how directly it works.

I would try calling

```
include 'zip:///path/to/myarchive.zip#file.php';
```

Unlike the phar wrapper the zip wrapper seams to require a sharp, but you can also try it with a slash. But it’s also just an idea from reading the docs.

If it does not work, you can use phars of course.

Comment: I tested your last suggestion with `include 'zip://' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.zip#test.php';` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @vascowhite: Thanks for testing. Would have done it myself, but I had to rush to university. Awesome that it works :)